# How to add a "#" in this href attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Right now, I'm using this:

```
// Scroll to matched dish
$("#scrolll").click(function() {
    $("a#scrolll").attr("href", $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

To add the ID of `li.matched` to `a#scroll`'s href attribute.
For example, if `li.matched` has an ID of `#menu123`, `a#scrolll` will look like this:

```
<a id="scrolll" href="menu123">
```

But I would like to make it look like this:

```
<a id="scrolll" href="#menu123">
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) to tack `#` at the beginning.

```
// Scroll to matched dish
$("#scrolll").click(function() {
    $("a#scrolll").attr("href", "#" + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

Additionally, since you're changing the element from inside an event handler for it, you can use `$(this)` rather than reselecting the element. (Cybernate noticed this first [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089698/x/8089709#8089709))

Answer (score 2):

Append "#" with the `+` operator.

Also you can replace `$("a#scrolll").attr` with `$(this).attr` since the code is in the click handler of `a#scrolll`

Try this:

```
$("#scrolll").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "#" + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the strings:

```
// Scroll to matched dish
$("#scrolll").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", '#' + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

You can use the `+` operator to join strings together. I also replaced your redundant selector with `$(this)`.

Also, be careful with your second selector `li.matched`. You aren't 100% sure that there is only *one* element with the class `.matched`, so your `attr("id")` could be undefined if there happen to be two elements with that class.